# SciPy differencial_evolution doesn't work out given number of iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scipy, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm unsuccessfully trying to learn my neural network to play pretty simple game. The problem is that differential_evolution() from scipy doesn't work long enough: I set `maxiter=1000` but function works only for 41 iteration.
here is the code:

```
def fitness_func(x, *args):
    #print('fitness func started')
    arch, width, height = args
    net = genome_to_nn(x, arch)
    my_game = Game_2(height, width)
    count = 0
    move = -1
    while count < 100:
        count += 1
        field = my_game.get_np_field()
        decision_tensor = net(field)
        move = int(tf.math.argmax( decision_tensor , axis =1))
        if move != 2:           
            my_game.make_a_move(move)       
        if count % 2:
            my_game.make_random()        
        my_game.next_iter()
    
    result = 1/(150 + my_game.score)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    field_width = 5
    field_height = 10
    inp_size = field_width*(field_height-1) + 1    
    
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Dense(10, input_dim = inp_size),
            layers.Dense(10, input_dim = 10 ,activation='sigmoid'),
            layers.Dense(3, input_dim =10, activation='softmax')
        ]
    )

    args = (model, field_width, field_height)
    bounds = np.asarray([(-10,10) for i in range(len(nn_to_genome(model)))])

    print('start evolution')
    res = differential_evolution(fitness_func, bounds= bounds, args=args, maxiter=50, workers=70, disp=True) 

    print('DE finished')
    
    fitted_model = genome_to_nn(res.x, model)
    
    print(res)
```

And then i get the following output:

```
start evolution
/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py:494: UserWarning: differential_evolution: the 'workers' keyword has overridden updating='immediate' to updating='deferred'
  " updating='deferred'", UserWarning)
differential_evolution step 1: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 2: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 3: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 4: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 5: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 6: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 7: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 8: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 9: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 10: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 11: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 12: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 13: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 14: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 15: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 16: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 17: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 18: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 19: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 20: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 21: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 22: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 23: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 24: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 25: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 26: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 27: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 28: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 29: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 30: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 31: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 32: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 33: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 34: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 35: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 36: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 37: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 38: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 39: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 40: f(x)= 0.00606061
differential_evolution step 41: f(x)= 0.00606061
DE finished
     fun: 0.006060606060606061
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 399735
     nit: 41
 success: True
       x: array([-6.59142662, -6.6655827 ,  7.01109519, -6.61588426, -8.99447424,
         ...
         just a lot of unnecessary numbers here
         ...
       -4.19133698,  1.62013289,  5.72924953, -0.29303238, -2.17649926,
        1.91011116,  9.8819633 , -9.58588766,  6.05450803])
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model_trained/assets
```

P.S. It doesn't matter if maxiter is 50 of 5000 (more than 41), the function still goes for 41 iteration

If i set `maxiter=30` i get the following:

```
message: 'Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.'
    nfev: 298425
     nit: 30
 success: False
```

UPD: I changed returning value of the fitness function to

```
result = - my_game.score
```

So, now the returning value is in range [-100, 100] (used to be in [1/250; 1/50]), and it works! But, i still have no idea why it's not working with the old version of function. The official documentation doesn't say anything about any restrictions on it's returning value (exept it should be a number)